# Facebook open graph doesn't return any instagram media

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I have opened this as a bug with facebook here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/105273653568982/
but thought I would ask here as well to see if anyone else has a solution:

The facebook open graph API says it is supposed to work for instagram as well as facebook, however when used from my server side code OR from the open graph explorer OR from postman, is only returning facebook media items, not instagram media items.

Eg a GET request for comments on my own facebook photo returns successfully:

Request:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=101205943227587%2Fcomments&version=v2.11&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2016-01-04T16:11:07+0000",
      "message": "People might be abl",
      "id": "101205943227587_1187008471313990"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before":"WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEU0TnpBd09EUTNNVE14TXprNU1Eb3hORFV4T1RJek9EWTQZD","after":"WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEU0TnpBd09EUTNNVE14TXprNU1Eb3hORFV4T1RJek9EWTQZD"
    }
  }
}
```

whereas endeavouring to get the same thing for an instagram post (again using my own media) doesn't work.

Request:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1531969816055084767%2Fcomments&version=v2.11&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

Result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 
1531969816055084767",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "D2xUM/kQWsJ"
  }
}
```

None of the methods here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/ 
work for instagram media, eg attempting to get the info about Instagram's own account

**GET graph.facebook.com
  /25025320?fields=biography,id,username,website&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN**

returns an error

```
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '25025320' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "DCreoeyTARt"
  }
}
```

My app has been approved to use the new api with the instagram_basic and instagram_manage_comments permissions, and I know the access token is valid as I am able to get facebook media and use the **graph.facebook.com/me** api so not sure why all instagram-related stuff is failing.

Comment: I get the same error. Using Facebook graph api gives me the same error. I have added `instagram_basic` permission which is needed to get comments for a insta media. Using the instagram endpoint in sandbox mode is working for the same media id: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/MY_INSTA_ MEDIA_ID/comments?access_token=MY_INSTA_TOKEN`